# Organize input data as a 3D configuration

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

My input data from "file.txt" is as follows (extract sample):

```
245.214
188.936
195.758
194.939
194.242
188.936
  ...
```

However, the software I use requires data to be organized as a 3D configuration

```
245.214 188.936 195.758
194.939 194.242 188.936
....
```

What would be the easiest way to convert input data? I use Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: I would call that "2D". Or in rows of 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get the required output with this code

```
awk '{if(NR%3 == 0){printf("%s\n",$0);}else{printf("%s ",$0);}}' ip_file.txt
```

Comment: Yes...i could have used the awk with the file directly.

Comment: @Raghuram Why not update your command then to do without `cat` and present a neater solution, be helpful to those a bit less versed with Unix/Linux (just a friendly suggestion)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [column](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/column/) command:

```
cat file.txt | column -c 28 -s "\ "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ xargs -n3 < file.txt mycommand
```

or, if you need it in another text file:

```
$ xargs -n3 < file.txt > foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Bash:

```
printf '%7.3f %7.3f %7.3f\n' $(<file.txt)
```